# c function that returns a value according to the caller's decision

Tags: c, generics

I'm trying to understand how else a generic function can work,
lets make it the easiest  example, if i want a function, to return max **or** min - according to the users choice, 
is it possible to do this as so:

```
  void f(void* a, void* b, void *(comp)(void* a, void* b), void* result){
 ////does something////
 }
```

or do i have to send some key as a parameter or there is another way?
thank you

Comment: Actually there are lots of ways, and you can choose the way that you prefer. This example  implies that the user will choose comparison function, but if you want something else write other function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling this function like this:

```
void* mincmpi (void* a, void* b) {
  return (*(int*)a < *(int*)b)? a: b;
}
//...
f (a, b, &mincmpi, res);
```

And inside f at some point call comp:

```
result = *comp (a, b);
```

Is certainly possible. One scenario for such a comparator would be sorting a sequence. Where you can specify the sort order via a function pointer. Although I suggest to not use void* if you do not really have to.